# Django template date filter not displaying

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a bit of a problem with displaying a datetime field in my template.

models.py:

```
date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

In my template:

```
{% for key, value in record.get_fields.items %}
    {% if key == field_name %}
        {% if value != "None" %}
            <div class="li-item">
                {% if "Date" in key or "date" in key and key not in do_not_display_fields %}
                    {{ value|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}
```

When I have the date filter, the dates are not displayed in the template though. If I remove the date filter, the date and time are displayed in this format:

```
2018-07-10T16:03:56.049408+00:00
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: What date filter?

Comment: {{ value|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}

Comment: Make sure value is `DateTime` field not `String`

Comment: this data value is a string! that's why it can't be displayed in the format passed

Comment: I am just displaying a field from the model.  I am not changing the datetime field to a string.  Am I missing something?  Is the datetimefield somehow changes to a string along the way?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same problem & I can't figure out why. It worked find in another template, but I copy-n-pasted it into another template and it suddenly won't display unless I remove the date filter.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="{{value|date:'Y-m-d'}}">
```

Remember there should not be space between colon(:) and 'Y-m-d'